# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while removing row from Excel in java

Tags: java, excel

```
for(Row row:sheet) {
  for(int rowNo=0;rowNo<sheet.getLastRowNum();rowNo++) {
    row=sheet.getRow(rowNo);
    sheet.removeRow(row);
  }
}
```

I am trying to remove the rows from Excel file through java but it is giving me error

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>       at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1207)
>       at java.util.TreeMap$ValueIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1252)

Comment: You look to be looping through the rows twice in the two for loops. Anyhow, it's the implicit iterator in the outer enhanced for loop which is complaining because you are changing the rows in the inner for loop.

Answer (score 1):

`TreeMap` does not support concurrent removals.

You should use `iterator`'s remove method

```
Iterator<Row> it = sheet.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    Row row = it.next();
    ... 
    it.remove();
}
```

Comment: hii James Wierzba, This is also not working giving me the same error

Comment: Can you explain why you loop over the rows twice? Are you excluding some code?

Comment: Actually we are processing one workbook which contain 27 sheets so i need to remove the 9th sheet rows and add new logic to write the  data

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be using the `row` from the outer for loop, so you can remove it:

```
for(int rowNo=sheet.getLastRowNum()-1; rowNo >= 0;rowNo--) {
  row=sheet.getRow(rowNo);
  sheet.removeRow(row);
}
```

Note also that I'm iterating the rows backwards, so you don't end up only removing every other row.

Comment: hii Andy Turner this solution is also not working

Comment: Please explain "Not working". Did you remove the outer loop?

Comment: Actually we are processing one workbook which contain 27 sheets so i need to remove the 9th sheet rows and add new logic to write the data

Comment: That doesn't explain what "not working" means.

Comment: not working means its giving me the same error as previous